# How to implement an efficient time to length transformation over velocity in Pyspark?

Tags: pyspark, time-series, etl

One machine provides data on thousands of sensors. The machine unwinds a metal stripe at time one. At the next time the metal strip is heated and at the third time the metal strip is cooled. Via a time stamp, the measured speed and a trigger (eg input / output oven), a band variable is to be generated in an ETL step.

```
+----------------+----------+-----------+---------+-----+
|time            |input_oven|output_oven|temp_oven|speed|
+----------------+----------+-----------+---------+-----+
|2017-01-01-01-20|0         |0          |450      |3    |
|2017-01-01-01-21|0         |0          |450      |3    |
|2017-01-01-01-22|1         |0          |450      |3    |
|2017-01-01-01-23|0         |0          |450      |4    |
|2017-01-01-01-24|0         |0          |451      |4    |
|2017-01-01-01-25|0         |1          |450      |4    |
|2017-01-01-01-26|0         |0          |450      |3    |
+----------------+----------+-----------+---------+-----+
```

As you can see, the speed can vary. I have tried the following code, but this is too inaccurate, also because the machine can stop, for example.

```
from scipy import integrate
s = lambda s: col_speed*col_time
integrate.quad(s, time_1, time_2)
```

Therefore, the integration must be performed via the speed variable so that the new meter variable can be generated. One file contains 30k entries of 5000 sensors.

The result need to be a table that parallels all the sensor data so that I can see: The metal stripe meter one has experienced the furnace temperature and that cooling rate.

Any help is very welcome and I thank you in advance.

**EDIT**

To give some further insights, I added the following picture.

[Time series of several sensor signals of one production line. The green line represents the current time. The yellow line represents the same length position at different times stamps.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dcWXa.png)

The goal of the ETL-job shall be the alignment of all sensor signals with regard to the length position. Therefore, I had the idea to use the following equation:

```
length = speed * time
time = time_delta(output_oven-input_oven)
speed = avg(speed)
```

With regard to the given example data, the equation should be solved like this for the complete DataFrame

```
length = avg(speed) * time_delta(output_oven-input_oven)
length = 4 m/min * 2017-01-01-01-25-2017-01-01-01-22
length = 4 m/min * 3 min = 12 m
```

Now I know which part of my metal stripe ran through the oven. Assuming my metal band is 12 meters long. I now want to lag all other sensor signals according to the length.

Comment: Can you provide a worked out example? Maybe for simple case of one time period that you hand calculated?

Comment: Thanks for your comment @sramalingam24. I added further information.

Comment: Are you trying to calculate the length for sheet through oven 1 or all ovens here?

Comment: I want to calculate the length over all sensors in every oven.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my attempt, is this close to what you want?

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as f
from pyspark.sql import Row

Columns = Row('time','input_oven','output_oven','temp_oven','speed')
x=[Columns(20,0,0 ,450,3),
Columns(21,0,0 ,450,3),
Columns(22,1,0 ,450,3),
Columns(23,0,0 ,450,4),
Columns(24,0,0 ,451,4),
Columns(25,0,1 ,450,4),
Columns(26,0,0 ,450,3)]

df = spark.createDataFrame(x).withColumn('id', f.lit(1))
df.printSchema()

df1 = df.withColumn('oven', df['input_oven']+df['output_oven'])

from pyspark.sql.window import Window

w = Window.partitionBy(df['id']).orderBy(df['time'])
cum_oven = f.sum(df1['oven']).over(w)
df2 = df1.select(df1['time'],df1['speed'], df1['output_oven'],cum_oven.alias('cum_oven'))
df3 = df2.withColumn('cum_oven', df2['cum_oven']-df2['output_oven']).drop(df2['output_oven'])

ws = Window.partitionBy(df3['cum_oven']).orderBy(df3['time'])
metal_length = (f.max(df3['time']).over(ws)-f.min(df3['time']).over(ws))*df3['speed']

df4 = df3.select(df3['time'], df3['cum_oven'], metal_length.alias('metal_length'))

fdf = df.join(df4, ['time'])
fdf.drop('id').sort('time').show()

+----+----------+-----------+---------+-----+--------+------------+
|time|input_oven|output_oven|temp_oven|speed|cum_oven|metal_length|
+----+----------+-----------+---------+-----+--------+------------+
|  20|         0|          0|      450|    3|       0|           0|
|  21|         0|          0|      450|    3|       0|           3|
|  22|         1|          0|      450|    3|       1|           0|
|  23|         0|          0|      450|    4|       1|           4|
|  24|         0|          0|      451|    4|       1|           8|
|  25|         0|          1|      450|    4|       1|          12|
|  26|         0|          0|      450|    3|       2|           0|
+----+----------+-----------+---------+-----+--------+------------+
```

Final integral is just a groupBy, max and a sum?

Comment: Thanks @sramalingam24! Works fine!

Comment: No problemo, you may need to number the ovens starting from one instead of zero for this to work on a complete dataset